# html style issue - style keeps migrating to preceeding element

Tags: html, css, styles

Have a quirky dilemma. I have illustrated it with the two attached images.

1 - I have a column containing 4 stories.

2 - ALL are styled the same.

3 - Visually - the bottom-most story appears wider.

4 - In firebug - there seems to be extra code as a "style" - which does not appear in the html.

---

5 - So, I removed the bottom story.

6 - And the "phantom" style now appears in the story above it. Making the story space above the deleted story wider. Just as it did the last story.

[See style in green - no idea where that came from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MKJn.png)

[When I delete a story section - the style in green appends itself to preceeding story](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIJdF.png)

---understand that I am dealing with a situation of an old website I needed to make mobile. There is a lot of CSS that might be affecting it - I;m just not sure where to start.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: There might be some Javascript code applying styling to the last element within the container. Have you tried searching for those CSS rules within your JS files?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Johnny K. - I've never heard of that or done that before. But it sounds, given the circumstance, that you are probably correct. Could you steer me as to how to go about that? I use firebug and sublime text 2.